# How to fix this php syntax error?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How to fix the syntax error on line 4.

```
    if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?> /img/sub_page/horizontal_separator.png" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" alt="" />',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Comment: What err message are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to reopen `php` as you are already echoing the string.

It Should be:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '<img src="'.bloginfo('template_url').'"/img/sub_page/horizontal_separator.png" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" alt="" />',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the string. You're trying to enclose PHP tags inside PHP. This will cause the tags to be output, but they won't be interpreted. You can use the string concatenation character of `.`:

```
'after_widget' => '<img src="'.bloginfo('template_url').'/img/sub_page/horizontal_separator.png" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" alt="" />',
```

For reference, in the future if you need to include single quotes in a string enclosed by single quotes, or double quotes in a string enclosed by double-quotes, you can escape them using `\'` and `\"` respectively. For example:

```
$myString = 'This isn\'t relevant';
$myString = "My name is \"Ben\"!";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a phpblock inside of a string

Change

```
    'after_widget' => '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?> /img/sub_page/horizontal_separator.png" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" alt="" />',
```

To

```
    'after_widget' => '<img src="' . bloginfo('template_url') . '/img/sub_page/horizontal_separator.png" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" alt="" />',
```